# Properties of the Scalar Field in Scalar-Tensor Theories

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gravity

I've been reading about [scalar-tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar-tensor_theory) theories of gravity, such as Brans-Dicke theory, and I started thinking about the scalar field. Now, I know that the Higgs field is a scalar field, and of course has a quanta, the Higgs boson. According to Wikipedia, the quanta of a scalar field will always be a spin-0 boson. What would the general properties of a boson arising from the scalar field in [scalar-tensor theories?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar-tensor_theory) How would it interact with other particles (if at all)?

Comment: Why do you think that it's any different than any other QFT? I think the usual procedure works fine: Look at the Lagrangian, find the terms the scalar field couples to, write down the Feynman rules.

Comment: That makes sense. I simply wasn't sure if it should be treated differently simply because it deals with gravity, but after some experimentation, it does seem you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACuriousMind has it right. The properties of a scalar field wouldn't in principle be different from any other scalar field theory. It depends on the Lagrangian for the theory of course, but the form of the Lagrangian would still be constrained by the same restrictions on other theories (general covariance, renormalizability, phase invariance of some sort, etc.).

The interactions would arise from a term like $\mathcal{L}_{int}\sim \lambda\phi (x) F(g_{\mu\nu})$ where $\phi(x)$ is your scalar field and $F$ is some function of the tensor field in question. In the case of Brans-Dicke theory, this term is $\phi R$ with $R$ the Ricci scalar for the metric tensor. The coupling constant would naturally determine the strength of the interaction.